# GraphQL, Apollo Server Federated schema

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I get this error while querying:

```
"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Transaction.createdAt."
```

This is the query:

```
query getMyTransactions {
  getMyTransactions {
    id
    createdAt
  }
}
```

The schema for this query is:

```
extend type Transaction @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
}

type Query {
  getMyTransactions: [Transaction!]!
}
```

And the other schema has `Transaction` type:

```
type Transaction @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String!
}
```

What's the problem?

EDIT: If I query for:

```
getMyTransactions {
  id
}
```

Works ok I and get all the `id` of the query, but if I include another attribute the query fails.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words - you declare `createdAt` type to be `non-null` value, but somewhere in your data `createdAt` is `null`.

`createdAt: String!`

> ! after the type name. This **means that our server always expects to
> return a non-null value** for this field, and if it ends up getting a
> null value that will actually trigger a GraphQL execution error,
> letting the client know that something has gone wrong. [GraphQl docs](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#lists-and-non-null)

#### Example

For this remote/local data (`createdAt` **missing** from the first object):

```js
const Transaction = [
  {
    id: "1",
    /* createdAt: "01/09/2020" */ /* missing from the data */
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    createdAt: "02/09/2020"
  }
];
```

Executing query

```
query{
  getMyTransactions {
    id
    createdAt
    }
}
```

throw error:

> "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field
> **Transaction.createdAt.**",

[image]

To solve this:

- **Option 1:** Add some **resolver** logic and/or add validation related to your required data.
- **Option 2:** Remove the require from `createdAt` (return `null` allowed):
  [image]

Comment: Thats what I thought but checking the data, createdAt exists on every item of the table. Now, if I put `createdAt: String` on Transaction type, I get each createdAt as null. I think I have a mistake on how Im using the federation options (@key, @external, etc)